# Code is getting stuck?

Tags: powershell, runtime-error, python-3.5

So I am on ex41 of LPTHW, but I am doing it in Python 3 rather than Python 2 I've fixed most of the errors, but I am hitting a brick wall on this one -- When I run my code, it just goes blank in powershell, then when I hit CTRL-C it gives me this error:

http://pastebin.com/iVCmCAWG

My code:

http://pastebin.com/5XPNGJe6

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, thanks to some help from learnpython subreddit and here as well, I realized my program would only ever run if I passed the args "english" to powershell. This is because the last while-loop would only print if the PHRASE_FIRST was set to True (which was when you passed the english arg in powershell).

therefore, I had to add an else statement in the case you did not pass an argument in Powershell and did not want to run it in english -> code form.

So essentially, what I added was:

```
else:
   print(question)

    input("> ")
    print("ANSWER: {0}\n\n".format(answer))
```

after the last if statement

Answer (score 0):

Hitting `CTRL-C` tells Powershell to stop the execution of the program, yielding a `KeyboardInterrupt` error.

A comment in the program mentions the following:

`# Keep going until they hit CTRL-D`

Meaning you'll have to exit with `CTRL-D`. That doesn't seem to work, so exiting with `CTRL-C` is logical. The program is broken at the line

```
question, answer = convert(snippet, phrase)
```

because we both got the same errors.

I've personally quit following the tutorial around Ex.25. Examing projects written in Python is far more effective because you can research the functions that the programmer/developer used for the project.

Comment: Sorry I was not specific enough in my post, I understand the whole CTRL-C thing, but how would you suggest I fix this error?

Comment: @Aaron, line 77 is `while True:`. Switching that to `for i in range(0, 20):` will run the function 20 times instead of forever.